# NumPy, .txt file not found

Tags: python, numpy

So here's my code :

```
climate_data = np.genfromtxt('climate.txt', delimiter = ',', skip_header = 1)
```

I put this python file in the same directory as the "climate.txt" file and I also already import numpy to my python file

And I get this error :

```
OSError: climate.txt not found.
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: An easy fix is trying to write the entire path so there would be no confusion

Comment: how are you running this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting this python script file in the same directory doesn't guarantee your code will be run in the same directory. To make sure of that, use absolute path to climate.txt, or you can get the absolute path to the script directory by writing:

```
import os    
DIR_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
climate_data = np.genfromtxt(os.path.join(DIR_PATH, 'climate.txt'), delimiter = ',', skip_header = 1)
```